# When site icon fails to load, it's taking down the whole Accounts section with it

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, design

As usual, much easier to explain with a screenshot: (sorry, no free hand circle seemed fitting)

> [image]

Networks/Proxies tend to hiccup, nothing we can do so this scenario is pretty common.

Enforcing height of 16 pixels on the icons would solve the design issue:

> [image]

And is one liner: (CSS only, class name is already there)

```
.favicon { height: 16px; }
```

Can this please be done?

Comment: `height`? Surely you mean `width`?

Comment: @Oded - height also fixes that.

Comment: @Oded well, shouldn't really matter as the size is symmetric. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Added class to the CSS.

Will be with you next build.